# how to get Celsius as output from LM335Z with arduino?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino

the firstsensor is my lm335z output.

```
int firstSensor = 0; 
int secondSensor = 0;
int thirdSensor = 0;
int inByte = 0;   

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  establishContact();  // send a byte to establish contact until receiver responds 
}


void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    inByte = Serial.read();
    firstSensor = analogRead(0);
    delay(10);
    secondSensor = analogRead(1);
    thirdSensor = analogRead(2);
    Serial.print(firstSensor, DEC);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(secondSensor, DEC); 
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.println(thirdSensor, DEC); 
  }
}

void establishContact() {

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on its [datasheet](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM135.pdf), the temperature output will vary at 10mV/K. But if you find a reference voltage at a known reference temperature, you can use this helpful equation from the datasheet:

`V_out = V_ref * T_out/T_ref` which is equivalent to `T_out = T_ref * (V_out/V_ref)`

So say your voltage is 2.982V at 25 degrees C or 298.15 degrees Kelvin (this is suggested in datasheet), then you can set your equation to:

`T_out = (298.15 Kelvin)(V_out/2.982V)-273.15`

So assuming you already can convert an analog reading into a voltage*, just plug in the measured voltage and this should give you your temp in degrees C.

*The Arduino has a built-in 10-bit ADC and the maximum voltage it can read is 5v. Therefore, you can factor in 5v/1024 ADC steps = 0.00488V per ADC step. (i.e. `V_out = firstSensor*0.00488`). So plugging in for V_out, the equation becomes:

`T_out = (298.15)(firstSensor*0.001637)-273.15` where 0.001637 = 0.00488/2.982.

Comment: Never multiply by a small floating point constant to get a value -- floating point is imprecise and often people don't enter enough digits in the constant to be precise -- 5 / 1024 = 0.048828125.

Likewise, be very careful with A/DC conversions as the range is not as you calculated.  An A/DC value of 1023 from an ATmega328 (uMC for the Arduino) is equal to Vcc  (supply voltage) -- not 1024.  That is, analogRead(A0) returns 1023 when the A0 pin equals Vcc.  You'll be off by 4.88mv (or more -- see previous) if you use 0.00488 as the value.  To check:

1023 * 0.00488 = 4.99224, or 1*K too low.